# Rails ajax dropdown menu set selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have ajax script which selects necessary data and returns array

**server response**

```
[{"id":67,"title":"first","selected":"first"},
 {"id":68,"title":"second","selected":"first"},
 {"id":69,"title":"third","selected":"first"}, 
 {"id":70,"title":"fourth","selected":"first"}]
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready ->
  category_id = $('#product_category_id').attr('selected', 'selected').val()
  product_id = $('#product_id').val()
  $.ajax
    type: 'GET'
    url: "/products/dynamic_admin_subcategory?category_id=#{category_id}&id=#{product_id}"
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (data) ->
      $('#product_subcategory_id').empty()
      subcat = $('#product_subcategory_id')
      $.each data, (value, key) ->
        console.log(key)
        $("<option />", {value: key.id, text: key.title}).appendTo(subcat);
        $("#product_subcategory_id option:selected").val(key.id).text(key.selected)
      return
  return
```

It works fine, but I cant set selected

Also i have tried

```
  $("#product_subcategory_id option[value=key.selected]").prop("selected", "selected")
```

but cant pass value to `option[value=key.selected]`
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it

changed

```
        $("#product_subcategory_id option:selected").val(key.id).text(key.selected)
```

to

```
        $("#product_subcategory_id option[value=#{key.selected}]").prop("selected", "selected")
```

`key.selected`== selected subcategory id